# Why is the Border CornerRadius not maintained for different BorderThickness?

Tags: wpf, winui-3, winui

Why does the `BorderThickness` changes the rendered `CornerRadius`?

Also, what is the design reasoning/philosophy behind it?
I just cannot understand it, maybe I'm missing something.

```
    <Border Width="300"
            Height="300"
            Background="Red"
            BorderBrush="Blue"
            CornerRadius="5"
            BorderThickness="50" />

    <Border Width="300"
            Height="300"
            Background="Red"
            BorderBrush="Blue"
            CornerRadius="5"
            BorderThickness="10" />
```

[image]

I see Rectangle has the same behavior.

Is there any element in WPF or WinUI which I can use to draw an exact radius so I can respect the designer's requirement?

Besides Path with custom points, I do not see any other way.
The issue with Path is I need to recompute the points myself when width/height changes which will hurt performance.

**EDIT: Trying to tweak the corner radius so that it can match the design spec turns out to be impossible.**

For example, let's assume the designer wants a Border with CornerRadius=5 and BorderThickness = 30.

In the image below, the top Border shows what an actual CornerRadius=5 looks like.

In the bottom Border, I try to meet the design spec. I set the BorderThicikness=30 and I tweak the CornerRadius to something very small so that it looks close to the corner radius of the Border above.
**But the CornerRadius remains quite big even for a very small value** `0.0000002`:

```
            <Border Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Background="Red"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    CornerRadius="5"/>

            <Border Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Background="Red"
                    BorderBrush="Blue"
                    BorderThickness="30"
                    CornerRadius="0.0000002" />
```

[image]

**EDIT #2:**

So that it's even more obvious how big the corner radius of the bottom Border is compared to the top one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the BorderThickness changes the rendered CornerRadius?

Looking at Border's method `OnRender`, there is a `Pen` which aim at drawing a rounded rectangle if `CornerRadius` property is set... the pen has `Thickness` Property, Pen's thickness = Border's thickness.

This is the flow of execution inside `OnRender` method when both `CornerRadius` and `BorderThickness` are set (in case of uniform thickness and uniform radius)..

```
pen1 = new Pen();
pen1.Brush = borderBrush;
pen1.Thickness = borderThickness.Left;
double topLeft1 = cornerRadius.TopLeft;
double num = pen1.Thickness * 0.5;
Rect rectangle = new Rect(new Point(num, num), new Point(this.RenderSize.Width - num, this.RenderSize.Height - num));
dc.DrawRoundedRectangle((Brush) null, pen1, rectangle, topLeft1, topLeft1);
```

So there is a Thickness-Radius trade-off that can not be avoided, And probably the only way to deal with it is to set a base border (the border that meets the designer's guidelines) and for the other border you would increase its radius if its thickness is less than the base border's thickness!

---

**Update**

Note that the dimensions of the border (`Width` and `Height`) is the third factor in the equation (see `DrawRoundedRectangle` call).

Imagine you are about to draw a rectangle of size 100x100 using a pen with thickness = 30.. You start drawing from the middle of the top line and moving the pen towards the left (image below).. Now, you will start  shifting the pen early before reaching the corner because you are not allowed to get out of the 100x100, and that will result in a big curve so the value of the radius will not take affect in this case because the `Width` and `Height` has higher priority that the `CornerRadius`.

[image]

So to let a very small radius like `0.0000002` take affect, you have to enlarge the dimensions of the rectangle to a size that a pen with thickness = 30 will look small enough to reache near the corners.

Here is the first xaml code after tweaking radius of the second border (set it to 20) to make it looks like the first border..

[image]

And to make the first border looks like the second border, you can change its code to this

```
<Grid>
    <Border
        Width="300"
        Height="300"
        BorderBrush="Blue"
        BorderThickness="10"
        CornerRadius="5" />
    <Border
        Width="300"
        Height="300"
        Background="Red"
        BorderBrush="Blue"
        BorderThickness="50"
        CornerRadius="5" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I do not understand your suggestion. Do you mean use two Border elements placed one on top of the other?

Comment: Also, do you mind share a link to the source code you mentioned? Is it on Github? Thanks!

Comment: This is [the code in github](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/cc3e63a38a43c1c920a08aa0987de35c60749cf9/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/Border.cs#L430), it is .Net Core implementation, variables' names are not identical to .NetFramework 4.8 (Because I've decompiled the net48 dll and copied the snippet of code from there), but the code is the same 100%.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. It looks impossible. Please see my edit.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the answer too, take a look please

Comment: Thanks. So you mean, instead of a Border, use a Grid with two Border elements, one on top of the other?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only way to overcome this issue..

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, that's my conclusion too, this is the easiest way to implement it, but it means tripling the number of elements just to make the corners and borders match the design. Definitely not OK for the performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. If you don't mind, I will leave it unanswered for a bit more time to try get more feedback, but otherwise I will mark your comment as an answer.